# How to make single zip archive with maven assembly plugin with predefined "src" descriptor?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, zip, maven-assembly-plugin

I was explicitly asked to make a package with the predefined "src" descriptor, but I can't get it to work.
This is my maven-assembly-plugin config in my POM:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>src</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>package</phase> <!-- append to the packaging phase. -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal> <!-- goals == mojos -->
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

I can make jar files with no problem, but I don't know how to produce the zip file. I am using eclipse, what option should I choose?

[image]

I also have a jar plugin which seems to make the jar all the time:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-jar</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>jar</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
```

Comment: The maven-jar-plugin is not needed to defined, cause it's defined by the life cylcle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to really execute the plugin, cause in pluginManagement the plugin is not really executed. So you have to change the following:

```xml
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>src</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>package</phase> <!-- append to the packaging phase. -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal> <!-- goals == mojos -->
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

into this:

```xml
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>src</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                    <phase>package</phase> <!-- append to the packaging phase. -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal> <!-- goals == mojos -->
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
 </build>
```

Afterwards just call

```
 mvn clean package
```

Comment: Thankyou, I was pulling my hair out before I found this